# Blur or hide screen portion during realtime presentation

Tags: video, presentations

I am about to present my project tomorrow. Demonstrating the project involves showing account name to certain game, as my project manipulates that games launcher. Basically, I am about to present what I have described in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjrcYsx6h1E). You can see how I blurred the "Username" column.

In the video, I have blurred certain things. I was wondering if I could similarly hide my information during presentation. Answer to my question could also apply to people who want to hide their taskbar.

Comment: Why not just create a new account that you don't mind people seeing the details for?

Comment: With which tool did you end up with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use on-screen annotation software to paint over the fields to hide before filling in their content. This would be in solid color though, not using a blur effect. The annotation "paint" will always be on top, but the annotation software will also allow you to use the windows below its layer.

For Windows, there is a list of software options [here](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/On-screen_annotation). For Linux, [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/328543).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Obscurit chrome extension from Chrome extension web store.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/obscurit